# Cannot get system variable via System.getenv(variable) in azure functions

Tags: java, azure-functions

I cannot get environment variable in azure functions.
I have added system variables via azure portal and dont get it using `System.getProperties() and  System.getenv()`.

I tried get it from code via `System.getenv("test")`, but response is `null`.

I also tried `System.getProperties()` to show all variables, but "test" doesn't appear there.

Finally I invoke from java code windows command line `Runtime.getRuntime() exec("cmd /c set")`
and there was the "test" param. According to azure documentation
[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#environment-variables)
 I could get param via `System getenv()`, but this doesn't work for me.

```
Java System.getenv("test") output from azure functions:
null

Java System.getProperties() output from azure functions:

java.runtime.name : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path : D:\Program Files\FunctionsJava\zulu8.36.0.1-jre8.0.202-win_x64\bin
java.vm.version : 25.202-b05
java.vm.vendor : Azul Systems, Inc.
java.vendor.url : http://www.azulsystems.com/
path.separator : ;
java.vm.name : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg : sun.io
(... and other java params)


Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c set") output from azure functions:
(...)
APPSETTING_test=teststext <- here exists with prefix APPSETTING :)
test=teststext <- and the variable test that i set
(... )
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure you have used `.` inbetween the `System.genEnv` coz i can see your question does not have that

Comment: Hey, yes, in code are dots. Only here I sometimes not write. I edit and add dots, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You are running local or azure and set the environment on the configuration or local.settings.json? Cause I test with local and azure, they all could get the env.

Comment: I run it on azure, and configure params via configuration gui on azure portal in app functions. Tried also on local and write values in local.settings.json ( "values" section), but not working.
@GeorgeChen if there was no problem for you, could try set variable in via configuration gui, run program on azure function to list variables and check where "test" variable appear for your program? 
here java code in pastebin : 
https://pastebin.com/vnnXg6np